# How to get rid of Typescript type error when overriding MuiContainer classes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

My app consists of two files: (https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ts-muicontainer-override-yywh2)

```
//index.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Button, Container, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import myTheme from "./myTheme";
function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={myTheme}>
      <Container>
        <Typography>
          <p>Some text</p>
        </Typography>
        <Button>dummy</Button>
      </Container>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);

//myTheme.ts
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
export default createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }
    },
    MuiTypography: {
      root: {
        color: "green"
      }
    },
    MuiContainer: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "yellow"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

The app displays the content on yellow background which means that my theme overrides work. However, the whole `MuiContainer` key in myTheme.ts is underlined red and the error says:

> Argument of type '{ MuiButton: { root: { backgroundColor: string; };
>   }; MuiTypography: { root: { color: string; }; }; MuiContainer: { root:
>   { backgroundColor: string; }; }; }' is not assignable to type
>   'Overrides'.
>       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'MuiContainer' does not exist in type 'Overrides'.ts(2345)
>   createMuiTheme.d.ts(20, 3): The expected type comes from property
>   'overrides' which is declared here on type 'ThemeOptions'

Indeed, it seems that `MuiContainer` is missing from interface ComponentNameToClassKey in mui overrides.d.ts. However, the MuiContainer [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/container/) says: *If using the overrides key of the theme, you need to use the following style sheet name: MuiContainer*. So I think the key should be correct.

How to fix the typescript type checking in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Passing an extended interface from `ThemeOptions` as

```
interface ThemeType extends ThemeOptions {
  overrides: Object
}
```

works fine for me

Answer (score -1):

For fixing the typescript issue what you can do is give **createMuiTheme** as type **any** for a quick workaround.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
export default (createMuiTheme as any)({        // Fixes the typescript warning.
overrides: {
    MuiButton: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "red"
      }
    },
    MuiTypography: {
      root: {
        color: "green"
      }
    },
    MuiContainer: {
      root: {
        backgroundColor: "yellow"
      }
    }
  }
})
```

I hope it helps. Thanks!

Comment: Not really a fix, is it? It's even better to just ignore the one error you are getting, instead of potentially introduce many more in the future.